# Is Restfull webservice with token a non standard

Tags: web-services, rest, restful-authentication, restful-architecture, webservice-client

My application flow is like this:

1. Client application first **request for a token**(token Resource) by sending Username/Password
2. Client application will **store that token** and let then user login(if credentials are valid)
3. Now client application will do **remaining api calls  with the token**
4. Once user do logout then, we remove token from client memory and invalidate token from server

In an interview I was asked that **this is not a pure RestFull** standard,because now **all your resources are dependent on token resource i.e before calling any api client must call token api and in this case there would become a tight coupling and sequencing in resources**.As per rest standards all resources should be independent.

So my question is:

**1. With token how can my resources become independent?**
**2. Is using token a non standard way?Then why lot of applications are using tokens.**

One approach is to use **basic authentication** with api instead of token but this way I will have to keep store username and password in client application till it is login.It is **not secure to save password in client application**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A quick look at the REST constraints

To be honest, I don't see any problems with tokens provided the application doesn't break the set of constraints defined in the [chapter 5](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of Roy Thomas Fielding's dissertation about REST:

- [Client-server](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_2)
- [Stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3)
- [Cache](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4)
- [Uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5)
- [Layered system](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_6)
- [Code-on-demand](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_7)

Let's have a look at the [stateless constraint](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3):

> [**5.1.3 Stateless**](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3)
>
> [...] each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on the client. [...]

If you are accessing protected resources that require authentication, every request must contain *all necessary data to be properly authenticated/authorized*, keeping the session state on the client.

An authentication scheme based on tokens is great when you don't want to send hard credentials, such as username and password, over the wire for every request. When using tokens, the hard credentials are sent once and exchanged for a token that must be sent in each request. Then the token becomes a credential and can be valid for a certain period of time.

Please mind that it doesn't matter the authentication scheme you go for, your server will need to validate the credentials sent in each request.

### JSON Web Token (JWT)

It's a standard method for representing claims securely between two parties, defined in the [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519). JWT is a self-contained token and enables you to store a user identifier, an expiration date and whatever you want (*but don't store passwords*) in a payload, which is a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) encoded as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

The payload can be read by the client and the integrity of the token can be easily checked by verifying its signature on the server.

To find some great resources to work with JWT, have a look at [http://jwt.io](http://jwt.io/).

### Keeping the track of the tokens

JWT allows you to perform *stateless authentication*, that is, you won't need to persist JWT tokens if you don't need to track them.

Althought, by persisting the tokens, you will have the possibility of invalidating and revoking the access of them. To keep the track of JWT tokens, instead of persisting the whole token, you could persist the token identifier (the [`jti`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) claim) and some metadata (the user you issued the token for, the expiration date, etc) if you need.

Your application can provide some functionality to revoke the tokens, but always consider revoking the tokens when the users change their password.

When persisting tokens, always consider removing the old ones in order to prevent your database from growing indefinitely.

Comment: Okay that means..One resource can be dependent on another resources?

Comment: @VibhorBhardwaj I don't see why an authentication scheme would create a dependency on your resources.

Comment: In rest we consider token as a resource, So we can not call  any resource directly  until I call token resource.

Comment: @VibhorBhardwaj I think now I understand what you mean by creating _dependency between resources_. For example purpose, let's consider an API that manages your favorite songs and there are the following resources: `track` and `playlist`. The `playlist` resource will have a _dependency_ on the `track` resource. Is it an issue? I don't think so.

Comment: Thanks for your example now I understand that Resource can be inter-dependent on each other and for calling one resource there may be the case you must call another resource. Only the important thing is it should be stateless.